# How do i update picture using sqlconnection

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlconnection

it always show an error Incorrect syntax near ')'.
I didnt see any wrong inputs

See my code below

```
byte[] content = ImageToStream(fName);

cnn.Open();
string sql = "update tblbarangayofficials set pic=@pic,fname=@fname,mname=@mname,lname=@lname,position=@position,startterm=@startterm,endterm=@endterm where id=@id)";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", SqlDbType.Image).Value = content;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtfirstname.Text;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtlastname.Text;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox2.Text;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startterm", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endterm", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(ID.Text);

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
cnn.Close();

MessageBox.Show("successfully updated");                
dataGridView1.DataSource = db.sp_viewofficials();
```

it should save to sql server my save works

Comment: `string sql = "update tblbarangayofficials set pic=@pic,fname=@fname,mname=@mname,lname=@lname,position=@position,startterm=@startterm,endterm=@endterm where id=@id)"; `<<< that's the error. you forgot the opening bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update statement has extra ending bracket which is not needed.

```
"update tblbarangayofficials set pic=@pic,fname=@fname,mname=@mname,lname=@lname,position=@position,startterm=@startterm,endterm=@endterm where id=@id"
```